# Links in sidebar fail on any page that is not the front - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

help!!

I amd having a serious problem. I am creating a custom theme using a child and I made my own sidebar to use as a nav. The links I added to other pages work fine only when I am on the home page. when I am on any other page, the link just appends the target url to the current url. Can someone please tell me whats going on? I have been looking for solutions for days and I can't find anything to help.
http://www.testjustfine.com/

Thank you!

Comment: We need to see the code for that sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links are being treated as relative URLs.

You either need to put a protocol (eg 'http://') at the start, or make them real domain-relative links by taking away the domain and starting with a '/'.

Comment: Thank you!  that is exactly the problem!